# VBA: Summing the rightmost cell per row?

Tags: excel, vba

I've a data set that looks similar to the below.

I'd like to average the data in the rightmost column only.

My range starts at `C4` with no set end to either rows or columns.

```
**1** 
1 **2** 
1 2 **3** 
1 **2**
**1**
```

I've put the following together which does what I need it to do for a single fixed column but I don't know how to expand that out to always use the value from the right most column.

```
Dim Sum, Count As Integer

       Count = 0
       Sum = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

       Range("C4").Select
       Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

           Sum = Sum + ActiveCell.Value
           Count = Count + 1
           ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

       Loop

       Range("O1").Value = Sum / Count
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will cycle the rows.

The MATCH will return the column number of the last column with a number in it.

Then we get the number on that row in that column and add it to an array.

Then after the loop we average the array.

```
Sub aver()
    With Worksheets("Sheet4") 'Change to your sheet
        Dim lastrw As Long
        lastrw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim num() As Variant
        ReDim num(1 To lastrw) As Variant

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 4 To lastrw
            Dim j As Long

            j = Application.Match(1E+99, Rows(i), 1)
            num(i) = .Cells(i, j).Value

        Next i

        .Range("O1").Value = Application.Average(num)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly and thanks for the explanation.